# why jquery and javascript blur event infinitiy loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, alert, blur

```js
$("div").on("blur kepress", 'input', function(evt){
    console.log(evt.type);
    if ( $(this).val().length > 8 ) {
        alert("loop");
        $(this).focus();
    } else {
        console.log(2);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div class="parent">
     <input type="text">
 </div>
</body>
```

If the length is greater than 8 fall into an infinite loop
I want to find a solution Please...

Comment: `kepress` -> `keypress`

Comment: because alert will focus out and trigger the blur listener again

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that calling `alert` *unfocuses* the element,  - it's the alert box that is the new focus. So, the `blur` event gets triggered on the `input` again, resulting in the whole listener function running again - it keeps triggering itself.

`alert` is very user-unfriendly anyway. Fix it by removing the `alert`:

```js
$("div").on("blur kepress", 'input', function(evt){
    console.log(evt.type);
    if ( $(this).val().length > 8 ) {
        $(this).focus();
    } else {
        console.log(2);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div class="parent">
     <input type="text">
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: we can also use `console.log` instead of `alert`

Comment: Removing the Alert is not always proper.  Alert is there for a reason:  to block execution until the end user acknowledges the issue and inform the user that there is an issue.  In many cases, it is appropriate to Alert, but NOT return focus to the original field, instead marking the field as invalid and letting the user return to it.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you are triggering "Blur" when you click the alert window, then it's re-focusing, then re-alerting, etc etc.